# Finding time difference and executing a condition

Tags: javascript

```
var currentTime = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000)
var previousTimeStamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000)

var difference = currenTime - previousTimeStamp

if(difference < 0 minutes) {
   execute some code
}
```

This condition is not getting executed.

Comment: `currentTime` and then `currenTime` ?

Comment: that is a verry weird statement ? shouldn't the 0 be = ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code order does not make sense and it has a typo in currenTime.

1) the two times are identical to almost a millisecond
2) there is no such thing as "0 minutes" in JavaScript

You want the difference to be less than 60000 milliseconds and use two different times

Do you mean

```
var previousTimeStamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000); // seconds
// here I guess some code comes which takes some time 
var currentTime = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000); // seconds

var difference = currentTime - previousTimeStamp

if(difference < 60) { // took less than a minute
   execute some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong in your code. First, you have `currenTime` instead of `currentTime`. Second, you have `0 minutes` which is not valid Javascript. Third, you probably meant one minute rather than zero minutes, since you only get less than 0 if the current time is *earlier* than the previous time. Fourth -- this may just be because you're giving illustrative sample code rather than the real thing -- you're actually measuring "current time" before "previous time stamp", which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that difference will be equal to 0. In this case 0 < 0 is false so code is not executed.

I think the resolution of the timer is quite big so keep this in mind as you will frequently get the same values for both time stamps.

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of mistakes in your code. Here is correct one.

```
var currentTime = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);
var previousTimeStamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);

var difference = currentTime - previousTimeStamp;

if (difference < 60) {
   alert(1);
}
```

Comment: I think 60000 is not correct since he has already divide the time by 1000

Comment: @Mario A. Corchero Jiménez True.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `minutes`, have you tried to use: `if(difference < 60)` coz you have already set they as seconds?